# How to contribute to small part of a large open source project

Tags: kotlin, open-source

I want to contribute in Kotlin and need a little bit of your help.
Actually, I cloned the [GitHub repo.](https://github.com/jetbrains/kotlin) But when I opened the project in my IDE(IntelliJ) it took 1.5 hours to build then another 45 mins to run tests which I had to stop in the middle as it was too much of waiting.
This is too much of time and I think their must be some way around it.
For now, I only want to get my hands on [Js Module](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/js) Is there any way possible that I could clone just that and don't have to worry for the other modules which would only increase build and testing times?

I asked this question on their [Slack channel](https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/15474975/hi-everyone-i-want-to-contribute-in-kotlin-and-need-a-little#5cc096e4-0730-466f-9999-54d67d0954a6) but haven't got any reply yet.

I cloned the repo and then build it with Gradle, but the build process takes too long and I can't contribute anything valuable to the repo.
I want that build process should only happen to modules I prefer working on so that the time could be reduced.